# Flip view controllers inside bigger view controller will flip the main view controller

Tags: objective-c, transition, viewflipper, flip

I want to flip a view controller which has smaller size than the screen. I am using *transitionFromViewController* but this would flip also the whole screen. And I want just the smaller view controller to be flipped.

First the login should be visible, after flipped the register view should be available!

My code is

```
- (void)showLogin {
    vcLogin = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:vcLogin.view];
    [self addChildViewController:vcLogin];

    if (IS_IPAD()) {
        vcLogin.view.center = self.view.center;
    }
}

- (void)showRegister {
    vcRegister = [[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:vcRegister.view];
    [self addChildViewController:vcRegister];

    if (IS_IPAD()) {
        vcRegister.view.center = self.view.center;
    }

    [vcLogin willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [self transitionFromViewController:vcLogin toViewController:vcRegister duration:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [vcLogin removeFromParentViewController];
        [vcRegister didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }];
}
```

I also tried with *[UIView transitionFromView:...]* but the result is the same!
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I have used [UIView transitionFromView:...] several times for subviews and it works as expected. Are you sure the frame of 'from' view is only a part of self.view.bounds?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried core animation? You might use something like the code below and have one view controller with subviews.

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:viewOne
                        toView:viewTwo
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                    completion:(^(BOOL finished){
    })];
```